# ArraySum only a certain rows in the cfoutput of a query

Tags: sql, coldfusion

I am trying to add only certain rows to this output. Currently this output adds all rows, which is used for a Total row at the very end of

```
<cfoutput query="qrySummary">

#numberFormat(ArraySum(ListToArray(ValueList(qrySummary.secThreeCount))), ",")#
```

This obviously totals all of SecThreeCount values, but what if I want to exclude the last 2 rows from that list??

Is that possible in coldfusion?

(If this makes a difference)>> So there are 13 rows returning, I want the first 11 rows and exclude the last 2.

I know that I can limit the SQL return of that query to exclude those 2 rows, but I wanted less code to write and keep things neat. And also learn if it is possible:)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Well I think if you don't need those two rows, you should not be returning them in the first place. That would be the best answer. From your statement "but I wanted less code to write" you're optimising in the wrong place: don't optimise *for yourself*, optimise for the solution.

Leigh's come in underneath me as I've been testing the code for this, but here's a proof of concept using `subList()`:

```
numbers = queryNew("");
queryAddColumn(numbers, "id", "integer", [1,2,3,4,5,6]);
queryAddColumn(numbers, "maori", "varchar", ["tahi", "rua", "toru", "wha", "rima", "ono"]);

maori = listToArray(valueList(numbers.maori));
subset = maori.subList(2,5);

writeDump([numbers, subset]);
```

This returns an array with elements `["toru","wha","rima"]`.

Comment: If you do use subList, rather than arraySlice, just note it handles indexes differently (as is typical with CF vs java functions). With `subList(fromIndex,toIndex)` the "fromIndex, [is] inclusive, and [the] toIndex [is] exclusive".

Comment: Yeah: the Java approach ain't so sensible IMO.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running CF10, one option is using [ArraySlice](https://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/ArraySlice). Grab only the first eleven elements, then apply `arraySum`.

```
  <cfset allValues = ListToArray(ValueList(qrySummary.secThreeCount))>
  <cfset subTotal = arraySum( arraySlice(allValues, 1, 11))>
```

For earlier versions, there is the undocumented [subList(...) approach](http://www.aliaspooryorik.com/blog/index.cfm/e/posts.details/post/using-slice-in-coldfusion-349). It takes advantage of the fact that CF arrays are `java.util.List` objects under the hood, and uses [`List.subList(..)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) to grab a subset of the array.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach.  You don't want to add up the values for the last 2 elements, so remove them from your array:

```
<cfset values = ListToArray(ValueList(qrySummary.secThreeCount))>

<!--- delete the last element --->
<cfset arrayDeleteAt(values, arrayLen(values))>

<!--- delete the last element again --->
<cfset arrayDeleteAt(values, arrayLen(values))>

#numberFormat(ArraySum(values), ",")#
```

Alternatively, given that you're looping over the query anyway, you could simply add the totals up as you go (with a tiny bit of logic to not bother if you're on the last or penultimate row)